# How would I go about adding functions from external python file to current python file?

Tags: python, python-import

I mainly want to use the import command to import functions to current_file.py. I tried doing:

```
from functions.py import *
```

but it throws an error:

```
current_file.py and functions.py files are in the same directory.
```

Comment: Hello! Just remove the `.py` so say `from functions import *`

Comment: As a general comment, never do `import *` (unless you are writing an `__init__.py` file). You can often import more than is required and can easily mess up your namespace without you knowing it.

Comment: As another general comment, the argument to `import` looks like it's vaguely a file name, but it's not. This comment box is too small to explain how a file name maps to a module name and vice versa, but see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove '.py' extension

like:

```
from functions import *
```

and if you wanna organize your files in a path of your own functions, you can import like this:

```
from [your function path].[your function files] import *
```